# How do I get all of a particular type of nodes in Gumbo Parser?

Tags: html, parsing, hyperlink, gumbo

I am trying to use Gumbo Parser to get all the nodes of a particular type - like all `<p></p>` nodes or all `<a href...></a>` nodes from a HTML document.

My function  prototype is like following:

```
list<GumboNode*> GetAllNodesOfType(GumboNode* root, <required type of nodes> )
```

What should I put in the place of second parameter `<required type of nodes>`?